# Mongoose, findOneAndUpdate, update into array, but duplicate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple schema:

```
var extraSchema = new Schema({
    key : String,
    value : String,
    id : String

});

var ItemSchema = new Schema({

  department : String,
  category : String,
  id : String,
  name : String,
  description : String,
  price : Number,
  seller : String,
  quantity : Number,
  extra : [extraSchema],
  visible : Boolean

});
```

I try to update an extra object into a Document Item, here is an example:

```
{
  "_id": "581cf2597b27281f04e8619e",
  "name": "300",
  "description": "The dvd of the movie 300",
  "price": 19,
  "seller": "BestDVD",
  "id": "1",
  "quantity": 10,
  "department": "581c783f41d2893b80f3b0ba",
  "category": "581c7f8441d2893b80f3b0c0",
  "visible": true,
  "__v": 0,
  "extra": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "value": ".100",
      "key": "weight",
      "_id": "581cf2667b27281f04e8619f"
    }
  ]
}
```

so I want to change the extra element of id 1 for a value of .250

I did the following:

```
  Item.findOneAndUpdate({'extra.id' : req.body.id},
              {'$set' : {
                'extra.$.key' : req.body.key,
                'extra.$.value' : req.body.value
              }}, function(err) {
                if (err) throw err;
              }
            );
```

When I do that, it does not update the extra element of id 1 but it duplicates the element and changes the weight:

```
{
  "_id": "581cf2597b27281f04e8619e",
  "name": "300",
  "description": "The dvd of the 300 movie",
  "price": 19,
  "seller": "BestDVD",
  "id": "1",
  "quantity": 10,
  "department": "581c783f41d2893b80f3b0ba",
  "category": "581c7f8441d2893b80f3b0c0",
  "visible": true,
  "__v": 0,
  "extra": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "value": "\".100\"",
      "key": "weight",
      "_id": "581cf2667b27281f04e8619f"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "value": ".250",
      "key": "weight",
      "_id": "581cf2857b27281f04e861a0"
    }
  ]
}
```

I do not understand what happens, does somebody have good idea?

Thanks in advance for your help

Cheers,
mph

Answer (score 0):

When used with update operations, e.g. db.collection.update() and db.collection.findAndModify(),

the positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the first element that matches the query document.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, and well, shame on me. It was a problem with Postman, actually I thought I was using PUT but it was POST corresponding to my feature add extra, I understand now why it never worked...

Need to cool down my brain, stupid problem